# spring batch not rolling on runtime exception in itemwriter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I am new to spring batch and I have a spring batch with spring data project with oracle database. Basically for simplicity I have 2 steps :

Step 1 : Read the first row of the csv file than insert in table_header in itemwriter

Step 2 : Read from the  second row of the csv file than insert in table_detail in itemwriter.

The table_header is linked to table_detail - one to many relationship.

Basically if a runtime exception in triggered in step 2 just after saving the detail while in the same step the data does not roll back.According to spring reference it should roll back on runtime exception.

I am not sure what i am missing in order for the transaction to rollback, can someone point me to the right direction pls?

Please find below my database configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "dummyEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "dummyTransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "com.dummy.persistence" })
@PropertySource("file:${test_PROPERTIES}")
public class DatabaseConfig extends HikariConfig {


    @Bean(name = "dummyDatasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(CipherWrapper.getInstance().decrypt(jdbcUrl));
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(CipherWrapper.getInstance().decrypt(username));
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(CipherWrapper.getInstance().decrypt(password));
        hikariDataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
        hikariDataSource.setMinimumIdle(minimumIdle);
        return hikariDataSource;
    }


    @Bean(name = "dummyEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dummyEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = builder.dataSource(dataSource())
                .packages("com.dummy.persistence.entity").persistenceUnit("dummyPersistenceUnit").build();

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());


        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean(name = "dummyTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager dummyTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("dummyEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory dummyEntityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(dummyEntityManagerFactory);
        jpaTransactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }


@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(@Qualifier("dummyEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory dummyEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
                @Override
                public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
                        return  dummyTransactionManager(dummyTransactionManager);
                }
        };
}
}
```

Please find below both step config:

```
@Bean("step1")
public Step headerSaveStep() {

StepBuilder stepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get(Flow.STEP1.toString());
SimpleStepBuilder<HeaderDetailsDto,HeaderDetailsAdditionaDto> simpleStepBuilder = stepBuilder
        .<HeaderDetailsDto, HeaderDetailsAdditionaDto>chunk(1);
simpleStepBuilder.reader(csvItemReader.csvFileVatPayerDetailsItemReader(null));
simpleStepBuilder.processor(EnrichmentProcessor());
simpleStepBuilder.writer(headerWriter());
simpleStepBuilder.allowStartIfComplete(true);
return simpleStepBuilder.build();
```

}

```
@Bean("step2")
public Step detailSaveStep() {

StepBuilder stepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get(Flow.STEP2.toString());
SimpleStepBuilder<DetailsDto, DetailsDto> simpleStepBuilder = stepBuilder
        .<DetailsDto, DetailsDto>chunk(20000);
simpleStepBuilder.reader(csvItemReader.csvFileBuyerDetailsFileItemReader(null));
simpleStepBuilder.writer(detailsWriter());
simpleStepBuilder.allowStartIfComplete(true);
return simpleStepBuilder.build();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your transaction manager is not being used by Spring Batch. You need to define a `BatchConfigurer` bean referring to it (See example [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/index-single.html#javaConfig)). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the bean batchConfigurer please see DatabaseConfig above but it is still same behavior.I guess i am missing some addidional  configuration here?

Comment: which version of Spring Batch do you use?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay to reply, I am using Spring Batch Core 4.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: ok thanks, the approach I showed in my answer works with version 4.1.0.RELEASE. For the record, this has been fixed in https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2294.